# Bash shell...find command...names with wildcards...alias or function

Tags: bash, function, alias, wildcard

I've long used the find command for finding files and directories in the current directory and all subdirectories that match a pattern:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print
find . -name "Bill*" -print
```

But what I'd really like is an alias or function that will properly pass the wildcard.  (I used to be able to do this in csh, but now I'm using bash.)  If an alias or function named "fn" were set properly, I could save some time by just typing:

```
fn "*.txt"
fn "Bill*"
```

Ideally, I'd like to lose the quotation marks too, but I'm guessing that might not be possible because the shell will expand them before calling "fn".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and will postpone carpal tunnel syndrome....  :)

SOLVED: After the discussion below, I put this in my .bashrc file:

```
fn () {
  find . -name "$1" -print
}
```

Note the quotes around the argument: "$1".  This can then be called with more quotes around the filename expression:

```
fn "*.txt"
```

EDIT: must have spaces between the function name and the parentheses, so
  fn () { ...   [works]
  fn() { ...    [doesn't work]

Comment: You'll need a function, not an alias, because the argument needs to go in the middle of the expansion.  `fn() { find . -name "$1" -print; }`

Comment: I tried this.  But the "$1" in the function gets expanded in the current directory.  So, if I try fn *.txt in a directory that has the file a.txt, then the command becomes fn a.txt instead of fn *.txt

Comment: Aha...  The answer below solved this.  I needed quotes both when calling and in the function description.  Thanks for the very quick replies!

Comment: You will always need to quote the argument to the function if it contains wildcards…but the function as written seems to work for me when invoked as `fn "*.c"`, for example.  You can't avoid quoting the wildcard expression in the invocation of `fn`.

Comment: I might have improved your solution slightly. By making my function `fn() { find . -iname "*$1*" -print}` I can just type `fn word` and I find all files with *word, Word, WORD, WoRd* or similar anywhere in the filename. That's what I was after, maybe you were after something different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately the wildcards must be quoted or the shell will expand them if possible.

Fortunately there are multiple ways of quoting them.

```
fn '*.txt'
fn Bill\*
```

Comment: Yes, I expected that.  :(  But I can live with that.  What I don't know how to do is to write an alias or function that I can include in my .bashrc file so that all I have to type is:  fn Bill* or similar.

Comment: Sorry.  My reply was vague.  I don't know how to write an alias or function such that all I have to type is:  fn "Bill*"    (I don't mind typing the quotes; I do mind having to type f i n d  - n a m e     - p r i n t  so frequently.  Thanks for the quick replies, btw!

Comment: I may be missing something, but my attempt to apply that straightforwardly didn't work.  I've edited the original post to show the function I tried and how it fails.

Comment: If you're quoting it in the function and you're quoting it in the command line then you should not be getting the results you're seeing.

Answer (score 7):

```
find ./ -name "*pbs.e*"  -type f -size +10c
```